# datatable empty but selectableDataModel has content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datamodel

after I run method cercaParametriPratica() , the DataTable seems to be empty, but the DataModel contains results (I print the number of records in an outputLabel).

Can anyone help me with this one please? I can't seem to find any solution for this problem, nor can't I find a mistake in my algorithm.

Using PrimeFaces 3.5

My code:

```
public String cercaParametriPratica() {

    String idCostante= this.getFiltroParametri().getCostanteFiltro();
    List<ConfigParamCalcParametro> listaParametri = null;
    ParametriCalcoloDataModel parametriModel = null;


        Integer annoMin = this.getFiltroParametri().getAnnoMin();
        Integer annoMax = this.getFiltroParametri().getAnnoMax();

        try {

            listaParametri = this.getPersistenceFacade().ricercaParametriFiltrata(
                    this.pratica.getNumeroPratica(), idCostante, annoMin, annoMax);
            parametriModel = new ParametriCalcoloDataModel(listaParametri);

        } catch(DatabaseException dbe) {
            log.error("Errore ricerca pratica {}", this.filtroPratica.getNumeroPratica(), dbe);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Errore!", "Errore nel ricerca dei Parametri di Calcolo."));
        }
return "gotoHome";
```

}

public class ParametriCalcoloDataModel extends ListDataModel implements
SelectableDataModel,java.io.Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 298627650136646161L;
private Map<String, ConfigParamCalcParametro> map;

public ParametriCalcoloDataModel(List<ConfigParamCalcParametro> data) {  
    super(data);
    map = new HashMap<String, ConfigParamCalcParametro>();
    for(ConfigParamCalcParametro item : data) {
        if(item != null)
        {
        map.put((String)getRowKey(item), item);
        }
    }
}  

@Override  
public ConfigParamCalcParametro getRowData(String rowKey) {  
    return map.get(rowKey);
}  

@Override  
public Object getRowKey(ConfigParamCalcParametro log) {  
    String key;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(log.getMeseRifIniz());
    sb.append(log.getAnnoRifIniz());
    sb.append(log.getIdCostante());

    key = sb.toString();

    return key;  
}

public int size(){

    return this.map.size();
}
```

}

```html
   
<pf:dataTable id="listaParametriDataTable" widgetVar="datatable" value="#{configParamCalcSrv.parametriModel}" selection="#{configParamCalcSrv.selection}" var="paramCalc" selectionMode="single" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="99%" resizableColumns="true"
            paginator="true" lazy="true" rows="10" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20" currentPageReportTemplate="Tot: {totalRecords}">

              <pf:column id="valoreColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.valore}">
                <f:facet name="header" style="text-align: right;">
                  <h:outputText id="valoreLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Valore" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="valoreText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.valore}">
                  <f:convertNumber locale="it_IT" maxFractionDigits="4" />
                </h:outputText>
              </pf:column>

              <pf:column id="meseRifInizColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.meseRifIniz}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="meseRifInizLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Mese Iniz. Periodo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="meseRifInizText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.meseRifIniz}" />
              </pf:column>
              <pf:column id="annoRifInizColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.annoRifIniz}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="annoRifInizLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Anno Iniz. Periodo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="annoRifInizText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.annoRifIniz}" />
              </pf:column>
              <pf:column id="meseRifFineColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.meseRifFine}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="meseRifFineLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Mese Fine Periodo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="meseRifFineText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.meseRifFine}" />
              </pf:column>
              <pf:column id="annoRifFineColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.annoRifFine}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="annoRifFineLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Anno Fine Periodo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="annoRifFineText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.annoRifFine}" />
              </pf:column>
              <pf:column id="utenteColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.utente}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="utenteModLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Utente Ult. Mod." />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="utenteModText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.utenteMod}" />
              </pf:column>
              <pf:column id="dataModColumn" sortBy="#{paramCalc.dataMod}" style="text-align: center;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText id="dataModLabel" styleClass="outputText" value="Data Ult. Mod." />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="dataModText" styleClass="outputText" value="#{paramCalc.dataMod}" converter="calendarCustomConverter" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
              </pf:column>

            </pf:dataTable>
```

Comment: Is the panelgrid relevant? If not, remove it from the code example

Comment: I should have referred to [mcve] and [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info on improving your question to. It is next to impossible to even try to replicate. And also try newer versions to see if something was fixed in the mean time